# Org-mode hook following creation of a new <<<radio target>>>

Tags: org-mode, hooks, hyperlinks

I want to call `org-update-radio-target-regexp` as soon as `org-mode` recognises that a new `<<<radio target>>>` has been created (which seems to happen as soon as the third `">"` is typed, at least this is when it gets fontified).

What hook can I use to get this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following NickD's input on my [first answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/63233/12695) (thanks @NickD) I think a better approach is to limit `org-update-radio-target-regexp` to only fire when the target is first created. This is done by binding the `">"` key and then testing whether point is just to the right of a `<<<radio target>>>` (after it is pressed). Here is the code:

```
(define-key org-mode-map (kbd ">")
  (lambda ()
    (interactive)
    (if (and (org-in-regexp org-target-regexp)
             (not (org-in-regexp org-target-regexp nil t)))
        (progn
          (insert ">")
          (org-update-radio-target-regexp))
      (insert ">"))))
```

Comment: Instead of binding the key globally, you should bind it in `org-mode-map` only, since you only want it active in Org mode buffers. You can then simplify the function by throwing away the testing of the mode.

Comment: Aha! Thanks NickD. All done.

Comment: Nice job! I think this is much more efficient than your initial attempt.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```lisp
(defun org-at-radio-target-p ()
  (not (eq (org-in-regexp org-radio-target-regexp) nil)))

(add-hook 'post-command-hook 
      (lambda () 
        (when (org-at-radio-target-p)
          (org-update-radio-target-regexp))))
```

I am not sure how efficient it is, hooking into `post-command-hook`. But it seems to work okay, so far...

Comment: The `post-command-hook` runs after *every* command: e.g. inserting a character in a buffer is done by the command `self-insert-command`, so the hook is going to run after every character you type in a buffer; BTW, that's *any* buffer, not just org mode buffers. If the buffer is large, you are going to be spending a lot of time looking for radio targets and even though the regexp is not particularly complicated, the searches are *not* free. If you find that when you type fast in a large buffer, emacs cannot keep up with your typing, then you have probably reached this limit.

Comment: The doc string for `post-command-hook` says `It is a bad idea to use this hook for expensive processing.  If
unavoidable, wrap your code in ‘(while-no-input (redisplay) CODE)’ to
avoid making Emacs unresponsive while the user types.`

Comment: And as a minor point, `(when (not (eq (foo) nil)) (do-something))` is equivalent to `(when (foo) (do-something))` - you probably don't need the `org-at-radio-target-p` function.

Comment: Finally (?), assuming that you want to check for radio targets *only* when you are in an Org mode buffer, you might want to write the hook function like this: `(lambda () (when (eq major-mode 'org-mode) (when (org-in-regexp org-radio-target-regexp) (org-update-radio-target-regexp))))`, so you only pay the penalty in Org mode buffers, not in every buffer. And in general, it is recommended that you name your hook functions: that makes it easier to delete them from the hook when the need arises.

Comment: @NickD thanks. Have you tested this? I was not able to get this to work...

Comment: That's `post-command-hook` I believe through `global-font-lock-mode-check-buffers`, but I really don't understand how that happens. In any case, font-lock has been specifically designed to run when emacs is idle, so I believe that the `post-command-hook` actions basically just set a flag (or flags) that are checked later: IOW, the functions that are called from `post-command-hook` are designed to not do very much processing at all.

Comment: I have not tested anything, but what is the "this" that does not work?

Comment: So I executed `(lambda () (when (eq major-mode 'org-mode) (when (org-in-regexp org-radio-target-regexp) (org-update-radio-target-regexp))))` but following this, moving point into a `<<<radio target>>>` does not trigger `org-update-radio-target-regexp`

Comment: "I ran ..." : what do you mean? You need to add it to the hook, instead of your `lambda` (or better: define a function and add the function by name to the hook, after getting rid of yours). The `post-command-hook` is still used: it's just that the function will not do much for non-Org mode buffers; for Org mode buffers, it will do what yours did.

Comment: Ah okay, I got it.

Comment: NickD So it looks like you can simplify this further to `(lambda () (when (eq major-mode 'org-mode) (when (org-at-radio-target-p) (org-update-radio-target-regexp))))`. The only issue is that this appears to fire with every key press, while point is on a radio target. It might be better if the function only did this once, unless the content of the target has changed...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119478/discussion-between-nickd-and-adam).